Animation busca mal el archivo JSON
En Genexus 18 U6, tengo un web panel en el cual quiero mostrar una Animation, siguiendo la documentación.
Al ejecutar el evento, el web panel no me muestra nada, y si veo la consola de desarrollador muestra el siguiente mensaje:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)                   Resources/Spanish/data.json:1

Pareciera que está buscando un archivo "Resources/Spanish/data.json" , en lugar de buscar el archivo "Resources/Spanish/PruebaGuidoAnimation.json" que es el que corresponde.
Así tengo definidas las clases en el Design System:
.Animation
{
    gx-animation-type: idLottie;
}

.PruebaGuidoAnimation
{
    @include Animation;
    gx-lottie-file: gx-file(PruebaGuidoAnimation);
}

Y esto es lo que ejecuto en el evento del WebPanel:
Event 'Ejecutar'
    AnimationView1.SetAnimation(StyleClass:PruebaGuidoAnimation, true)
    AnimationView1.Play()
Endevent


Para solucionarlo deberías agregar esta línea en la clase de la animación:
.PruebaGuidoAnimation
{
    @include Animation;
    gx-lottie-file: gx-file(PruebaGuidoAnimation);
     --gx-lottie-file-path: "PruebaGuidoAnimation.json"; //Nombre del archivo mas .json
}

